# show text as it is entered in input box

Tags: django

I have created a Q&A website in Django I want to print text in the same format as it entered

```
This is the text
This is on a new line
```

It should print in this format as it is entered but it prints like this

```
This is the text This is on a new line
```

my forum.html code

```
 <div class="card-body cardbody">
                      <p>{{post.post_content|truncatewords:"10"|linebreaks}}</p>{% if post.post_content|length|get_digit:"-1" > 50 %} 
       <a href="/discussion/{{post.id}}" data-abc="true"><button class="btn btn-light" style="color:blue; font-size: 13px;">Show more </button>  </a>
 {% endif %}
</div>
```

please help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) mentions:

> Newlines within the string will be removed.

Hence you need to use the `linebreaks` filter first and then instead of `truncatewords` you should use `truncatewords_html`:

```
{{ post.post_content|linebreaks|truncatewords_html:10 }}
```